# Passing a string parameter in a JavaScript function on MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, string

I tried to pass a string value into a JavaScript function like below:

```
<%= "'" + prop.property_description + "'") %>)
```

But it does not seems to be the best option, is there a better way to do the above without concatenate the string values with "'"?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know ASP.net, but couldn't you just put the `'` s outside? `'<%=prop.property_description %>')`

Comment: What happens if `prop.property_description` contains a `'`? To Javascript this will now appear as `'foo'bar'`, which is a syntax error. A little more context wouldn't go amiss to help people better answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your javascript function is being called inside an html tag ie `<div onclick="javascriptfunction">` you can do the following initialize a new string variable using inline .net tags(`<%=%>`) like so  `<%=string strVar = "'" + prop.property_description + "'")%>` then add it to your tag like so `<div onclick="javascript:function(<%=strVar%>);">` this will avoid the `'` conflict you can also whenever your dealing with strings and want to add `"` inside a string initialization just add `\"` to the string like so `"john said \"Hi There \""` if you want your string to end until the end `"` is called add `@` infront of your string init like so

```
@"Hello
  World"
```

This allows your string to span multiple lines without havig to add an extra + for every new line you want to format.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to have an MVC application in front of me currently and I checked that this:

```
var test = "<%= Model.SearchTerm %>";
```

Results in the following output:

```
var test = "Example";
```

Which means you don't need to concatenate the quotes as you have in your example - you can place the entire C# block inside the quotes.